# ReflectionException in Route.php Class Controller does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 in a centos 5.8 server and getting the following error:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class xxxx\Http\Controllers\CpanelController does not exist


ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412: include(/home/xxxx/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/CpanelController.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I am trying with:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`chmod -R 777 storage`

`composer dump-autoload`

But the problem persists

Comment: Instead of `chmod -R 777 storage` try `chmod -R 777 your_root_dir`

Comment: Have u checked the namespaces? Or maybe u have some group routes namespaced differently?!

Comment: You shouldn't chmod your root dir with 777, that is the bad way to fix your error, you need to try chmod 777 `vendor` and `/vendor/composer` folder, re-check your namespace also

Comment: Thanks. I dealt with chmod permissions in vendor, vendor/composer and the main folder but still nothing. I checked the controller and it is in the correct location. Any other suggestions?

Comment: check the spellings and uper & lower case for controller file.

Comment: can you show the routes you made for that

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR The upper and lower cases are good and this is the routes files: Route::resource('cpanel','CpanelController');
 Route::get('editmovie','CpanelController@showmovie');
 Route::get('selectuser','CpanelController@selectuser');
 Route::get('selectpassword','CpanelController@selectpassword');
 Route::get('selectrange','CpanelController@selectrange');
 Route::get('approvemovie','CpanelController@approvemovie');
 Route::get('approveMovieToNotif/{id}','CpanelController@approveMovieToNotif');
 Route::get('editfromnotif/{id}','CpanelController@editfromnotif');

Comment: are these routes inside a route group, which uses any namesapces

Comment: Check namespace of your CpanelController

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Throughs Reflection Exception when it does not find a class which is pointed in String.

There are some points to remember.

1. Make Sure you have a correct namespace in your class which you are trying to access.
2. Check the upper & lower case for controller file. Upper case and lower case doesn't matter in WINDOWS but it is not going to work in Linux/CentOS.
3. run `composer update`
4. give Permission to whole directories as 777 and file have 644